# c# - rounding time values down to the nearest quarter hour

Tags: c#, rounding

Does anyone have a good way to round **down** a number between 0 and 59 to the nearest 15.
I'm using C# 3.5.

So ...

- 1 would be 0
- 29 would be 15
- 30 would be 30

etc etc.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`x = x - (x % 15)` would be a solution that doesn't rely on integer division.

Answer (score 18):

As an extension method on the datetime

```
public static DateTime RoundDown(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 
         dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, (dateTime.Minute / 15) * 15, 0);
}
```

to use

```
DateTime date = dateTime.Now.RoundDown();//for example
```

Comment: Make sure to fit an abstract factory pattern in there somewhere for a more decoupled design.

Comment: Hey, I'm an extension method junkie. I offer no apology ;p

Answer (score 5):

How about (x / 15) * 15?

Comment: You'll have to make sure that x is an integer type, first, however...  (Or, at least, cast x / 15 to int)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a library call for this (like .Round(...)), perhaps and extension method would fit nicely?

I would go for a simple IF statement.

If speed is an issue, try an expanded switch statement for each value. Use unit tests to see whats faster if that's an issue.

To be complete...

```
//...
[TestMethod]
    public void round_down()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(-5.RoundDown(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(0.RoundDown(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(1.RoundDown(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(20.RoundDown(), 15);
        Assert.AreEqual(42.RoundDown(), 30);
        Assert.AreEqual(48.RoundDown(), 45);
        Assert.AreEqual(59.RoundDown(), 45);
        Assert.AreEqual(90.RoundDown(), 45);
    }
```

//...

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static int RoundDown(this int val)
    {
        if (val < 0)
            return 0;
        if (val < 15)
            return 0;
        if (val < 30)
            return 15;
        if (val < 45)
            return 30;
        return 45;
    }
}
```

Comment: He could also use a mocking framework to mock out the integer too for better testability (plus without all the overhead of integer allocation on the stack)

Comment: um no... the timing thing is because I assume that this is on a web site and there probably lots of it going on, that's all...

Comment: my assumption is that 0 is the lower boundary (59 the upper)

Answer (score 3):

You can use integer division -

```
int number = 43;
int newNumber = number / 15;
int rounded = newNumber * 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where the modulus operator comes in really handy

```
number - (number % 15)
```