# c# Round minute to nearest quarter only if more than 5 minute window

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to round the time minute to nearest quarter up and down only if the difference is more than 5 minute.
I have date time in the format "2019/02/19 10:05 AM"

10:05 = 10:00 
10:06 = 10:15 
10:20 = 10:15 
10:21 = 10:30 
and so on.

Round down to 0,15,30, 45 if there are less than 5 minutes in the difference, or round up to 0,15,30,45 when there are more than 5 minutes
Let me know how I can achieve this.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: @mjwills for 10:05:30 it should make 10:15 as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# - rounding time values down to the nearest quarter hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293186/c-sharp-rounding-time-values-down-to-the-nearest-quarter-hour)

Comment: You can achieve this by trying something, and if that does not work, then asking for assistance. Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

Searching found this method which will round up to the nearest quarter of an hour

```
private DateTime MyRoundTime(DateTime date)
{
  TimeSpan roundMins = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15); 
  return new DateTime(((date.Ticks + (roundMins.Ticks - 1)/2) / roundMins.Ticks) * roundMins.Ticks);
}
```

this will round up after 7.5 minutes after the quarter hour. What you want is to round up after the 5th minute, so simply add 2.5 minutes to the original time.

```
private DateTime MyRoundTime(DateTime date)
{
  TimeSpan roundMins = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
  date += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.5);
  return new DateTime(((date.Ticks + (roundMins.Ticks - 1)/2) / roundMins.Ticks) * roundMins.Ticks);
}
```

Comment: This seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was looking for. @PaulF

Answer (score 0):

You can use modular arithmetic:

```
    static DateTime RoundTime(DateTime dt, int roundInterval, int roundPoint)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = dt.TimeOfDay;
        int modInterval = ts.Minutes % roundInterval;
        if (modInterval < roundPoint || (modInterval == roundPoint && ts.Seconds == 0 && ts.Milliseconds == 0))
        {
            return dt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, modInterval, ts.Seconds));
        } else
        {
            return dt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, roundInterval - modInterval, -ts.Seconds));
        }
    }
```

It takes in a DateTime, and an interval and returns the rounded version. Call like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RoundTime(new DateTime(2019, 2, 19, 11, 35, 30), 15, 5));
        Console.WriteLine(RoundTime(DateTime.Now, 15, 5));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

You can then format the returned DateTime as you wish ("AM"/"PM" etc)

Comment: I don't think that this produces what the op asked. To begin with you don't consider the seconds IE: _10:00:01_ should result in _10:05:00_ (or 01). Then the OP has asked to round down to 0,15,30, 45 if there are less than 5 minutes in diff, or round up to 0,15,30,45 when there are more than 5 minutes. Your solutions rounds always to 5 minutes intervals-

Comment: @Steve that's what I'm looking for. You explained it better.